# Modelling a scenario involving architecture firms projects

Tags: database-design, erd

I'm very new to Database Modelling (using the Finkelstein methodology) and I'm getting confused on a modelling scenario in particular.

I am able to draw out the basics, however am running into some confusion with the intersecting and possibly types of entities (when the scenario refers to building style preferences).

**Business rules**

The relevant business domain is as follows:

- An architectural firm has a number of architects working for it.
- An architect may have more than one style of buildings they like to design on.
- The firm’s clients hire the architects to work on a building projects. Each building project may have a number of architects who work on the same project over a period of time.
- We need to record the project start date and the amount of time each architect spent on the project.

**My current advance**

What I have so far is this:

[image]

**Question**

Can someone please tell me if I'm moving in the right direction?